# Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=28 "No space left on device" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=28, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}

Tags: ios, sdwebimage

We use SDWebImage download remote image from network. The SDWebImage use NSURLSession download image.

But we got strange error log that somebody cannot show image because got error `Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=28 "No space left on device"`
This error happens rarely and cannot reproduce.

And we collect disk usage info and make create file test. We cannot find abnormal phenomena.

When the user met the problem reopen our app again and image can show again.

This is very strange, anyone met the same problem? I can sure this is not SDWebImage issue, seems like system issue.

Comment: maybe some problem with caching the images in SDWebImage?

Answer (score 0):

I've encounter the same error while continuing Prefetching Collection View image Data (willBeginBatchFetchWithContext in ASCollectionNode of Texture more accurately) the memory raise up to 189MB and the error had been throw.

https://www.bountysource.com/issues/65445186-error-domain-nsposixerrordomain-code-28-no-space-left-on-device-userinfo

and yet I've found the solution, you should give it a try.

I think you can just retry the request when receive the error cause it just need to take a little time for system to release more space for you.

Answer (score 0):

In case somebody is looking for iOS enum for this error code:

```
#define ENOSPC          28              /* No space left on device */
```

So my checking code looks like this:

```
error.code == ENOSPC && [error.domain isEqualToString:NSPOSIXErrorDomain]
```

I caught this error in the middle of file loading from web when device storage was almost full (file size 160 MB, free space 60 MB). Hope this will help somebody.